# mysql use a different set of WHERE statements if this=1

Tags: mysql

I need to do a single select on a table, but if Product='football' I need to do a couple of WHEREs, but if Product='something' then do something else. I am not sure if I need to do an IF statement, or a UNION or a CASE which I have never used.

Example of what I would like to have worked but obviously doesn't

```
SELECT *
FROM
    orders
IF Product = 'Football'{
WHERE
AND RenewalDate < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
AND RenewalDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
}ELSE IF Product = 'Something'{
AND RenewalDate < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
AND RenewalDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
}
ORDER BY
    RenewalDate
```

Now I know that looks like php but its just to show roughly what I want to happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `if` required.  Just boolean logic:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM orders o
WHERE (Product = 'Football' AND
       RenewalDate < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
       RenewalDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
      ) OR
      (Product = 'Something' AND
       RenewalDate < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND
       RenewalDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
      )
ORDER BY RenewalDate;
```

Comment: I need to select some other stuff i.e. renewaldate,
 DATEDIFF(renewaldate, CURDATE()) AS DaysUntilRenewalDate,
 orders.*

Comment: Does that change this at all?

Comment: @LewisSmith . . . You can add whatever expressions you like to the `select`.